# What kernel version does Elementary 5.1 use?

Tags: release-hera

I know my hardware doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04, but it does work with 20.04. I know Elementary 5.1 'updated' the kernel, but it's not stated what version it updated to.

Answer (score 1):

It uses version 5.3.0-51 when eos is up to date.

regards.